# Investigate the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{2^n}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Investigate the convergence of the two series
>
> 1. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{n^n}$$
> 2. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{2^n}{n^2}$$

Attempt

1. $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{n(1+1/n)^{n+1}}\to0<1$$
   then by D' Alemberts' test the series is convergent.  Correct?
2. Let $v_n= \frac{2^n}{n^2}$
   I want to check the convergence by Leibnitz's test. How to show that $\{v_n\}$ is monotonic decreasing and $v_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

Comment: Note that $2^n/n^2\to+\infty$

Comment: @RobertZ Means it is divergent. Q1. How to check $2^n/n^2\to+\infty$, Q2. Is it sufficient that $2^n/n^2\to+\infty$ implies series is divergent?

Comment: But D' Alembert's theorem is applicable for the series of positive terms? Here it is an alternating series.

Comment: Sorry. I mean $\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}\to 2>1$ implies that $|u_n|\to +\infty$ and therefore the series is not convergent (a necessary condition for convergence is $u_n\to 0$).

Comment: @user1942348 $$\frac{2^n}{n^2}=\frac{e^{n\log(2)}}{n^2}\ge \frac{1+n\log(2)+\frac12 n^2\log^2(2)+\frac16 n^3\log^3(2)}{n^2}>\frac16 \log^3(2) n$$

Comment: @RobertZ $\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}\to 2>1$ implies that $\sum|u_n|$  is divergent but does it imply that $\sum u_n$ is divergent

Comment: The limit of $S_N\sum_{n=1}^N u_n$ as $N\to +\infty$ is UNDEFINED: $S_{2N+1}\to +\infty$ and $S_{2N}\to -\infty$

Comment: @user1942348 If the general terms of a series do not approach $0$, then the series diverges.  Inasmuch as $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^n}{n^2}$ does not approach $0$, the series diverges.  That is all we need.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $v_n= \frac{2^n}{n^2}$, both conditions do not hold:
$$1) \ v_{n+1}>v_n \iff \frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}>\frac{2^n}{n^2} \iff 2n^2>(n+1)^2 \iff n^2>2n+1,n>2\\
2) \ \lim_{n\to\infty} v_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{n^2}\overbrace{=}^{L'H}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n\ln 2}{2n}\overbrace{=}^{L'H} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n\ln^22}{2}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to (1) is correct.

For (2),
the ratio is
$\dfrac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{2^{n}}{n^2}}
=\dfrac{2}{(1+1/n)^2}
\to 2
$
so this sum diverges.